# Is "if not already exists" valid English?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, negation, programming

In the programming world, I've often seen and used the phrase:

Create new table **if not already exists**.

Is this valid English wording and/or grammar?

Comment: I'd recommend "Create [a] new table if one does not already exist."

Comment: No, it's not grammatical. However, it's not a sentence but a fragment, so it works. Such structuring is common in the given context because of good readability, being unambiguous and simple.

Comment: Btw, 'English" always starts with a capital "E".

Comment: Thanks Kris. That capital E in English keeps disappearing from my memory. Having Norwegian as a native language sure doesn't help. And having learned German doesn't help much either - as they capitalize all nouns...

Comment: @Kris There's more wiggle-room with fragments, but this is outlandish.

Comment: Funny that you would still capitalize the word "I", then. Excuses, excuses. :-P Seriously, though, there's your mnemonic right there: in English you have to show languages the same respect that you have for yourself. Also, Kris is not entirely correct. You totally can spell *english* with a lower-case E, it's just that it means a completely different thing: the spin you put on a ball in billiards. So simply remember that "english" is not the same as "English", just like "march" is a completely different thing from "March", and "trump" is a completely different thing from "Trump".

Comment: Yeah, it's just excuses :P

Comment: Uh, what does "valid English" have to do with the "programming world".  They exist is different universes.

Comment: @HotLicks Most content in the "programming world" is written by writers qualified in "valid English" while more and more programmers too are now being trained in the English language and usage. It's not like geeks write gibberish in the tech world. Visit some tech sites and see the brilliant language.

Comment: @Kris - I can tell you from experience (40+ years of it) that you are wrong.  Yes, published content is often written or edited by skilled "pubs" people, but code comments are often indecipherable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clause *if not already exists* is programming [jargon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon) found primarily in inline documentation or reference to it. In the interests of economy, it violates the syntax of standard English as if the words in bold *if **it doesn’t** already exist* were mere adjuncts that could be omitted. The original expression, as Laurel pointed out in a comment below, was the even more truncated `IF NOT EXISTS`in MySQL, language used not between people, but people and computers.

> If selected and [*if not already exists*](https://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/Website%20Edition/002_HowTo/001_MigrationActions/006_HierarchyOptions.htm), a document set will be created with name as specified in the value of the specified Property column for each document item.

Jargon is a subset of a standard language created and used by a discourse group engaged in an activity or profession — sports, high finance, investment banking, the military — where technical terms may be coined whose meaning may be completely opaque to those outside the group until it is promulgated by print, broadcast, or digital media. For instance, during the Financial Crisis many, unfortunately, discovered what it meant to have an [*underwater mortgage*](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/underwater-mortgage.asp).

Computer jargon even has its own dictionary, the [*Jargon File*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon_File), which as all dictionaries will have a certain prescriptive and standardizing effect, in this case including lexical and semantic features distinct from the standard language.

Who first coined a word or expression — or at least where it first appeared — is apparently part of programming lore. This would suggest a certain status accrues to those who provide the discourse group with economical or mildly amusing coinages such as *kludge*, which in turn suggests one reason why this particular group is so productive in inventing new words.

In programming contexts, the use of *if not already exists* is standard. If at home a programmer says:

> Hey, I can’t find that jar of black olives for the salad. Can you run to the store if not already exists?

then I’d begin to worry.

Comment: The specific piece you're missing is that `IF NOT EXISTS` is [used in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859469/6083675).

Comment: I love the black olives joke

Comment: @Laurel: that makes it even more fun, since the origin lies in an expression used to talk to a machine rather than humans. I'll add that.